# Serializing a class with dependencies

Tags: c#, serialization, dependency-injection

So I have this class here

```
public class McalCommunication : IMcalCommunication
{
    private readonly IServiceLayer _serviceLayer

    public McalCommunication(IServiceLayer serviceLayer)
    {
        _serviceLayer = serviceLayer;
        _serviceLayer.UpdateModules();
    }

    public List<I2CPort> I2CList { get; set; } = new();
    public List<SpiPort> SpiList { get; set; } = new();
    public List<UartPort> UartList { get; set; } = new();


    public List<I2CPort> GetEnabledI2CPorts()
    {
        return I2CList.Where(i2CPort => i2CPort.Enabled).ToList();
    }

    public List<SpiPort> GetEnabledSpiPorts()
    {
        return SpiList.Where(spiPort => spiPort.Enabled).ToList();
    }

    public List<UartPort> GetEnabledUartPorts()
    {
        return UartList.Where(uartPort => uartPort.Enabled).ToList();
    }
}
```

As you can see the class `McalCommunication` depends on `IServiceLayer` which is injected by my DI container, the problem is that I need to Serialize this class but whenever I deserialize it the the json deserializer creates the object not the DI container which makes the `serviceLayer` null


So after some research I made this class

```
public class McalCommunictionData 
{
    public List<I2CPort> I2CList { get; set; } = new();
    public List<SpiPort> SpiList { get; set; } = new();
    public List<UartPort> UartList { get; set; } = new();
}
```

and I had to do the following modification to the `McalCommunication` class

```
public class McalCommunication : IMcalCommunication
{
    private readonly IServiceLayer _serviceLayer;
    private McalCommunictionData _data = new McalCommunictionData();

    public McalCommunication(IServiceLayer serviceLayer)
    {
        _serviceLayer = serviceLayer;
        _serviceLayer.UpdateModules();
    }
            
     public void ImportData(McalCommunicationData data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public List<I2CPort> GetI2CPorts()
    {
        return _data.I2CPorts;
    }

    public void SetI2CPorts(List<I2CPort> ports)
    {
        _data.I2CPorts = ports;
    } 

    ...

    public void GetEnabledI2CPorts()
    {
        return I2CList.Where(i2CPort => i2CPort.Enabled).ToList();
    }

    public List<I2CPort> GetEnabledI2CPorts()
    {
        return I2CList.Where(i2CPort => i2CPort.Enabled).ToList();
    }

    public List<SpiPort> GetEnabledSpiPorts()
    {
        return SpiList.Where(spiPort => spiPort.Enabled).ToList();
    }

    public List<UartPort> GetEnabledUartPorts()
    {
        return UartList.Where(uartPort => uartPort.Enabled).ToList();
    }
}
```

But as you can see that resulted in a lot of unnecessary code, also isn't this a "feature-envy",
So is this the right way to do or did I make a mess?

Comment: You should not try to serialize this class. Instead you should split the class into a class that holds the data and the class that  contains the behavior and dependencies. The former can than safely and easily be serialized.

Comment: @Steven Yes I know that, and as you can see I did split the class but, my question is if this is the correct way to do it, because splitting the class resulted in "feature envy" you can search about it

Comment: I would say splitting the class is *the* solution. Not doing so makes the component stateful, and forces you to hook into your serialization framework. Most serialization frameworks have poor support for that.

Comment: @Steven I do not know if you have read the question because I already did split the class, but I am asking if I am doing it in the right way "The best practice"